# Who is your top 5 or who are your top 5?

Tags: who

Can someone help me with this one? I don't know if I will use is or are with this? Is is correct to use Who is your top 5 most beautiful artist? or Who are your top 5 most beautiful artist? Thank you so much

Comment: 'Who are your top 5 greatest artists?' ('beautiful' would default to referring to the artist rather than their work).

Comment: You can use ***is*** if you talk about a list.  Who is in your “top 5 most beautiful artists” list?

Comment: @Jim — Not very beautiful. Try “list of…” You’ll be amazed what prepositions can do for your writing.

Comment: @David- whatever. My point stands.

Answer (score 1):

"Who are your top five..." is correct. "Are" is used because you refer to multiple artists in your list.